# How can I add selected option values to a jQuery multiselect from a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery multiselect and want to add option values to it from a form.

In the code I've constructed so far, I have "food: mac & cheese" and "supplements: vitamin e" selected. If I type in "coke" in the input field and select "drinks" from the drop down, how can I add it as "drinks: coke" into my jQuery multiselect while clearing the form (so additional text and drop down items can be added)?

edit: my question is how can i get "drinks: coke" selected so it's blue (and gray in the drop down since its selected) like "food: mac & cheese" and "supplements: vitamin e" using the HTML form? sorry if I did not explain well before.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.26.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.26.0/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<select id="multiple" multiple>
  <option value="value 1">drinks: lemonade</option>
  <option value="value 2">food: hot dog</option>
  <option value="value 3" selected>food: mac & cheese</option>
  <option value="value 4">food: pizza</option>
   <option value="value 8" selected>supplements: vitamin e</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<form>
  <label for="fname">food name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="type">Choose a label:</label>
  <select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="value 5">food</option>
    <option value="value 6">drinks</option>
    <option value="value 25">drugs</option>
    <option value="value 50">supplements</option>
  </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
new SlimSelect({
  select: '#multiple'
})
  //]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
new SlimSelect({
  select: '#multiple'
});

const btnAdd = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

let input = document.querySelector('#fname');
let select = document.querySelector('#type');
let selectOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#type > option');
let selectMultiple = document.querySelector('#multiple');

// create option element
let option = document.createElement('option');
let optionContent = selectOptions[select.selectedIndex].textContent+':'+input.value;
option.value = optionContent;
option.textContent = optionContent;

// insert in select multiple
selectMultiple.appendChild(option);

// reset input and select
input.value = '';
select.selectedIndex = 0;

})
```

Comment: Hi @v3rlly. thank you, but I replaced the JavaScript with your code and it broke the script. What did I do wrong? Here is my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bvky40jq/2/

Comment: I forgot the closing tags " }) "
try again and see if it works

Comment: thank you, that fixed it! but, this may have been my fault, how do I get it so the added option is selected in blue (and gray in the drop down since it is selected) like "food: mac & cheese" and "supplements: vitamin e"?

Comment: You can use the **setAttribute** method to mark the option as selected. add this snippet of code `option.setAttribute('selected', '');` before the **appendChild** method

Comment: thank you so much, you're wonderful my friend!!!!!!!